# Поехала вёрстка во всплывающем окне меток

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Поехала вёрстка.

Вероятно, из-за длины локализованных строк?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предлагаю варианты:

- проксировать баг на метумет, дабы не ломать перевод
- убрать слово "метку" с обеих кнопок

В пользу первого(или обоих) варианта приведу ещё один снимок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Или самому на метумет написать? Что-то лениво)

Comment: look: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313248/379531

Comment: ;( https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313249/230511 Удалил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сократим до «отслеживать» и «игнорировать», спасибо.

Я также создал вопрос на вселенской Мете, предлагаю проголосовать за него — может быть, тогда он удостоится внимания разработчиков: [Troubles with translated tag pop-ups](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313248/379531).

Comment: Совет юному переводчику: прежде чем утверждать переводы на Transifex, можно проверить как поведёт себя раскладка страницы, используя возможности редактирования html-страницы по месту. Например, в Firefox это можно сделать через контекстное меню "Исследовать элемент", далее, внести правки и посмотреть на результат.

Comment: @alexolut благодарю вас, о сэнсэй!

Comment: @alexolut, с другой стороны, почему перевод должен зависеть от вёрстки. Починят)

Comment: @vp_arth я вот о том же думаю, _адаптивный_ дизайн делали, а прореху оставили.

Comment: @vp_arth потому что таким не заморачиваются в SO. Хотя, может теперь всё изменится, но я не уверен, что дизайн будет в приоритете всё равно.

Comment: Кстати, не забудьте про "Не отслеживать". А то мало ли)

Comment: @vp_arth не забыл )

Comment: @vp_arth из 8ми [моих BR по дизайну, связанные с локализацией](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A339911+%5Bdesign%5D+%5Bbug%5D+%5Blocalization%5D), только 1 отмечен красной меткой.

Comment: @alexolut, это ведь не означает, что они не исправлены?

Comment: @vp_arth если оно исправлено и не отмечено, это может лишь говорить о халатности разработчиков :)

Comment: А про "перестать игнорировать метку" таки забыли ...

Comment: С "Перестать игнорировать" что-то надо придумать. Удаления "метку" оказалось недостаточно... :( Мб, "Не игнорировать"?

Comment: @vp_arth не игнорировать, да